# Can I override child elements using a base 'class'?

Tags: css, sass

Using SCSS, I'd like to style all `h3` elements that are of type `.some-base`, but it seems like I need to define the override in the derived styles. So

Doesn't work:

```
.some-base {
    h3 {
       margin-right: 3px;
    }
}

.some-derived {
    @extend .some-base;
}
```

Does work:

```
.some-base {

}

.some-derived {
    @extend .some-base;
    h3 {
       margin-right: 3px;
    }
}
```

Any way to get the first method to work so I don't need to redefine this in each override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.some-base` doesn't have any styles applied to itself. If you put `color: red` on `.some-base` in example 1, you'll see it inherited by `.some-derived` (note: it needs to go in `.some-base`, not `.some-base h3`).

It's not possible to extend nested classes though, so you can't extend `.some-base` and get the `h3` styles defined inside it (100% sure on this one), nor can you extend `.some-base h3` **if it's defined as a nested class**. If you define `.some-base h3 {}` as its own rule instead of `.some-base { h3 {} }` then you can extend it (95% sure on this one).

Comment: It doesn't look like I can extend from your latter suggestion - so I guess I just have to manually apply this particular style override!